# Ionic Android is always showing dark mode error

Tags: android, css, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic6

I've been creating a very small app with a menu some chips and a searchbar. But the problem is that I have forced MD theme in all app as you can see here:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(
      {
        mode: 'md'
      }
    ),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But in android it keeps seeing like this even android is Light Mode:

[Android Screenshot (Click me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE5RZ.jpg)

So anyone knows why it is always displaying in dark mode and how to fix it? I want the mobile devices to switch from dark to light when system is in that mode not only dark.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **index.html** in **src** folder in root of your project.
2. **Search with "light dark"** and remove  **"dark"** from the line.
3. Open **themes/variables.scss** file and search **dark**.
4. Remove the block that has **"Dark"**.
5. Restart the app and find the difference.

Comment: Okay now it changes. But if I want to change the dark theme colors? I have this variables.css now https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/lukewohuje.scss

Comment: I'm in the same situation now how can i modify the dark theme colors?